# How to get a gradle jar manifest attribute in the Java code (or set it via Java variable)

Tags: java, gradle, manifest

I have in my `build.gradle` (normal Java project) following attributes to be generated in the manifest:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'some.package.MyMainClass', 'Build-Number': '124'
    }

    classifier = 'main'
}
```

Now I would like to print this Build-Number value inside my Java code.
Can I access this attribute value in my code somehow?

Or the other way round,
can I define a `final String BUILD_NUMBER = 124` somewhere in a Java Class and insert/reference that value in the `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use property file with token replaced. But MANIFEST.MF should be good as well.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ReadJarManifest {

    private static Properties manifestProps = new Properties();

    static {
        try(InputStream manfStream = ReadJarManifest.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")) {
            manifestProps.load(manfStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("unable to read manifest " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(manifestProps);
    }
}
```

cmd line

```
-bash$ java -cp samples-1.1.jar ReadJarManifest
{Manifest-Version=1.0}
```

Comment: Thanks this works! One question though: Ideally, is there a way to have build.gradle reference a variable in a Java class? That way I could print out the Build-Number regardless of it being packaged into a JAR with a manifest or not.